# how to bootstrap EntityManagerFactory with externally-provided Connection and TransactionManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Am writing a "component" (`.jar`) to be loaded and executed by a 3rd party application. This application has an API to provide me with a Connection and also `TransactionManager`. My component is expected to participate in already running transactions, so should not have apply any transaction management (`close`, `commit` and `rollback` are forbidden on the provided Connections). For entities-related code I use JPA with Hibernate implementation

which approach should I use in order to have my `EntityManagerFactory` use these externally provided connection and transaction manager? For pure Hibernate I've found mentions of `ConnectionProvider` interface, which supposedly should allow me to provide any Connection I want, but I could not figure out a way to use this for `EntityManagerFactory`, and also I don't exactly understand the role of `TransactionManager`.

I've tried to implement a `SimpleConnectionWrapperDataSource`, where I basically wrap the provided connection in a dummy DataSource implementation, but this fails because `EntityManager` tries to close transaction on it before using it, and this is a forbidden operation. So how do I explicitly tell EMF to never mess with my connections ?

Answer (score 0):

My colleague has figured out a way to workaround this problem. The solution boils down to:

1) Implementing `ConnectionProvider`, which returns the container-provided instance of `Connection` on every call to `getConnection` (and also has empty body for `closeConnection` method)

2) Specifying class name of this implementation as `hibernate.connection.provider_class` JPA property

3) Providing `TransactionManager` as follows:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
    return new JtaTransactionManager(TransactionManagerUtils.getManager());
}
```